# Почему не работает фон

Tags: php, css

Получается вот что:

Задаю фон вот так:

```
$background = 'url('.$file['url'].');';
```

При рендере фон не отображается, хотя если глянуть стили - увидим:

```
background: url(http://site.ru/img.png);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я возьму и просто вручную вставлю точно такой-же стиль - все работает.

У меня есть лишь одно подозрение - `$file['url']` не строка, хотя я пробовал `strval`

При этом, если я сделаю 
`<img src="<?= $file['url'] ?>'/>` - выводит изображение

Comment: eval посмотри..

Comment: спс. Чего сам не додумался не знаю))) 
У меня получается  в url "\1" заменяется на ""

Comment: мне тоже не давно подсказали про eval )